# Opentelemetry Java TypeInstrumentation unable to typeMatch internal class

Tags: java, instrumentation, open-telemetry

I am trying to instrument `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse` function.

To do so, I created a `TypeInstrumentation` with the following `typeMatcher` function -

```
public class DocumentBuilderInstrumentation implements TypeInstrumentation {

    @Override
    public ElementMatcher<TypeDescription> typeMatcher() {
        return named("com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl");
    }
```

but I can't get it to work, it never instruments there objects...
I think it's because the class is "internal", but I am not sure how to bypass it.

Also tried - `return nameContains("DocumentBuilderImpl");` without any luck...

Any ideas what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

["com.sun.*" classes are ignored by default](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/d22dd8c5f132f681b577ccac949ae41f69139d48/javaagent-tooling/src/main/java/io/opentelemetry/javaagent/tooling/ignore/GlobalIgnoredTypesConfigurer.java#L87).

You should be able to add an [IgnoredTypesConfigurer](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/main/javaagent-extension-api/src/main/java/io/opentelemetry/javaagent/extension/ignore/IgnoredTypesConfigurer.java) to your instrumentation module which allows instrumentation of that specific class.